# How to control strange behavior of Ext.NET ComboBox controls?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, ext.net

I have few [Ext.NET](http://www.ext.net) ComboBox controls on a Web Form. Selecting an item from the first fires the ValueChanged event to populate the second, and so on.

Except *Force Selection* property, I have not altered other properties of the ComboBox control.

I am experiencing odd behavior of Combo Box controls. As all controls get filled via AJAX request, I find it difficult to set focus on any control. As soon as I bring focus on any control, the cursor disappears after it gets filled.

Secondly, one of the ComboBox is not permitting me to select an item from the list. Even if I try to select an item, it automatically brings back the default item back, which is actually a sixth item in the list.

I double checked the queries and there is no way through which sixth item should get selected.

If I try to open the DropDown list using mouse, it opens for few seconds and collapses automatically.

Is there any way to fix these strange issue? Any other third-party open-source control?

Comment: Posting a simplified .aspx code sample demonstrating how to reproduce the issue will get you a fast and accurate answer.

Comment: Sample to reproduce is not possible as there is no way to send you sample data.

Comment: ok, thanks for the update. When you get more information regrading the problem and can post a code sample demonstrating how to reproduce, we'll be happy to assist.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that combos are rebinded in each ajax requests
I suggest to rebind combos in Select direct event handler 
Also see the following sample
http://examples1.ext.net/#/Form/ComboBox/Ajax_Linked_Combos/